# Обучение базовой логике

Tags: python

Всех приветствую!

Вопрос достаточно нестандартный для этого места,но больше спросить негде)

Мой друг решил заняться программированием, я его немного коучил на начальных этапах, но появилась проблема. Он часто не понимает как простроить базовую логику даже в самой простой программе на том же питоне при достаточном понимании синтаксиса.

Я сам уже не вспомню как учился этому, было это давно, так что думаю здесь есть люди котороые смогут помочь.

Вопрос в том, на каких платформах или задачах можно это потренировать с условием супер низкого уровня? Начиная с задач условно с одним условием и по вощрастающей.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте платформу `codewars.com`